# Getting input text box value of display type "Number" in Client Side Java Script (CSJS)

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino

I've been trying to get the value of input text box from Client Side like this:

```
var CKQtyToDate = XSP.getElementById("#{id:CKQtyToDate}");
var CKQtyToDate = XSP.getElementById("#{id:CKQtyToDate}");
var SLQtyToDate = XSP.getElementById("#{id:SLQtyToDate}");
var FinishingQtyToDate = XSP.getElementById("#{id:FinishingQtyToDate}");
var PackingQtyToDate = XSP.getElementById("#{id:PackingQtyToDate}"); 

if ((parseInt(CKQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(SLQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(FinishingQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(PackingQtyToDate.value))>parseInt(hContractQty.value))
{
    alert("Total qty more than contract qty! =" + parseInt(CKQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(SLQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(FinishingQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(PackingQtyToDate.value));
    return false;
}
```

But I'm still having the result which is only string concatenation,how can i get through this thing???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Javascript parseInt returns NaN when parsing an empty string. So make sure to test for empty strings before doing the calculation. You can test if the string can be parsed by using `!isNaN(string)`.

I believe  that your problem is that you concatenate strings in your alert box. I will suggest that you move the calculation to a seperate variable and then concatenate the message string with this variable in the alert box:

```
var result = parseInt(CKQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(SLQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(FinishingQtyToDate.value)+parseInt(PackingQtyToDate.value);

if (result>parseInt(hContractQty.value))
{
   alert("Total qty more than contract qty! =" + result);
   return false;
}
```